# How do I track POST requests?

Tags: c#

While I was doing my program which checks accounts for correctness of entered data (password and login) I came across POST requests. Soon I started using Fiddler, but I found out that it doesn't track all POST requests. I found this after I had no line below:
username=...&password=...&return=aHR0cHM6Ly9maWYuY29tLw%3D%3D&9a9bd5b68a7a9e5c3b06ccd9b946ebf9=1
Full POST request:

```
-------------------------------------------------
POST https://fif.com/login?task=user.login HTTP/1.1
Host: fif.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 114
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://fif.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://fif.com/login?return=...==
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: 34f8f7f621b2b411508c0fd39b2adbb2=gnsbq7hcm3c02aa4sb11h5c87f171mh3; __utma=175527093.69718440.1410315941.1410315941.1410315941.1; __utmb=175527093.12.10.1410315941; __utmc=175527093; __utmz=175527093.1410315941.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmv=175527093.|1=RegisteredUsers=Yes=1

username=...&password=...&return=aHR0cHM6Ly9maWYuY29tLw%3D%3D&9a9bd5b68a7a9e5c3b06ccd9b946ebf9=1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I fix it? Or how do I track this line in other ways?

P.S. Please do not scold me for English grammar and for the moments that you will not like. I am new to programming.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, this may help... https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: If you are building a web application then you can log all of these information by use of a middleware, filter or in-line code in your end point. What do you mean by "it doesn't track all posts requests"? For testing APIs I recommend using Postman. Not too familiar with fiddler since I only use that seldomly.